# How to implement paging in Silverlight 3 datagrid?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I was trying to implement Grouping and paging in silverlight 3's datagrid, I found ways to do the both with help of `PagedCollectionView` class,

but the problem is I need tradition ASP.Net datagrid like paging, how could I do that? any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using .NET RIA Services which includes a DataPager control.  You can wire the scenario up in Xaml fairly easily, here's an example:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/04/27/paging-with-the-silverlight-ria-services-domaindatasource.aspx